# Simple html dom parse find element with class having no children

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have html structure

```
<body>
 <div class="nc">
     <a href=""> Main Heading</a>
 </div>
 <div class="props">
   <div class="nc"> Sub Heading</div>
   <div>
      <span>properties details1 </span>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="nc">
     <a href=""> Main Heading 2</a>
 </div>
 <div class="prop">
   <div class="nc"> Sub Heading2</div>
   <div>
      <span>properties details2 </span>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="prop">
   <div class="nc"> Sub Heading3</div>
   <div>
      <span>properties details3 </span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

What I want is to get output as below

```
Main Heading1
Sub Heading1
properties details 1

Main Heading2
Sub Heading2
Properties details2
Sub Heading3
Properties details 3
```

When I try to find `class=nc` with `find('div[class=nc]')` it returns all elements with `class=nc`, I want only parent elements having main titles. And then `Sub Headings` accessed through properties, so I can put them in array with proper order.

Comment: `$('.nc').find('a');` is titles

Comment: what code have you written so far?

Comment: foreach ($html->find('div.nc') as $nc)
{
 if(null !== $nc->find('a',0))
 {
  echo $nc->find('a',0)->href; echo "<br>";
  echo $nc->find('a',0)->plaintext; echo "<br>";
 }
 
}

Comment: This above code gets me href inside `class=nc`, but i want `class=prop` as well right after that. As it is part of the record. Hope it make sense from structure.

Comment: Please update your question to include your code. Writing code in comments makes it hard to read the code.